# How do i check that the next element in the list isnt out of bounds?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So i am trying to prevent the segfault that is occuring in the following code. It is occuring because i am trying to access the next element in the list that does not exist yet. How do i prevent this?

```
while (vm->item_list.head->data !=NULL) {

    printf("%-10s",vm->item_list.head->data->id);

    printf("%-20s",vm->item_list.head->data->name);

    printf("%-70s",vm->item_list.head->data->description);

    printf("%-15d",vm->item_list.head->data->on_hand);

    printf("%s","$");
    printf("%d",vm->item_list.head->data->price.dollars);
    printf("%s",".");
    printf("%02d",vm->item_list.head->data->price.cents);
    printf("\n");
    vm->item_list.head = vm->item_list.head->next;

}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I hope that linked list has a head pointer somewhere *besides* this `vm` construct, because if not this loop is guaranteed to leak/orphan the entire list, leaving the `item_list.head` member NULL, then promptly segfaulting. (and it is highly likely that is core to the problem). Run this in a debugger and step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

use something like `while ((vm->item_list.head != NULL ) && (vm->item_list.head->data !=NULL))`

Comment: `vm` is allocated properly?

Comment: ... as well as vm->item_list?

Answer (score 0):

In the initialization phase of the list, you have to declare the end of the list, in this case your next pointer, with NULL. If you do this, than you ensure that this pointer doesn't point in a undefined region.
So than you can check like this:

```
while (vm->item_list.head->data !=NULL) {

    printf("%-10s",vm->item_list.head->data->id);

    printf("%-20s",vm->item_list.head->data->name);

    printf("%-70s",vm->item_list.head->data->description);

    printf("%-15d",vm->item_list.head->data->on_hand);

    printf("%s","$");
    printf("%d",vm->item_list.head->data->price.dollars);
    printf("%s",".");
    printf("%02d",vm->item_list.head->data->price.cents);
    printf("\n");

    if(vm->item_list.head->next != NULL){
      vm->item_list.head = vm->item_list.head->next;
    }else{
      break;
    }

}
```

Or you can do it like this:

```c
ItemNode* node = vm->item_list.head;
while (node->data !=NULL || node->next != NULL) {

    printf("%-10s",node->data->id);

    printf("%-20s",node->data->name);

    printf("%-70s",node->data->description);

    printf("%-15d",node->data->on_hand);

    printf("%s","$");
    printf("%d",node->data->price.dollars);
    printf("%s",".");
    printf("%02d",node->data->price.cents);
    printf("\n");

    node = node->next;
}
```